# Delegate on tap of - button on UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Is there any delegate that gets called when we tap on the "-" button and delete button comes on the cell on the right side. I want to disable some label on the cell once this button is tapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you swipe on the row of UITableView it will call

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

after tapping on the delete button it will call

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and finally

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```